# why I have to define driver for sql db in maven project manually

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, spring-boot, jdbc

I have encountered issue, while I was setting up maven project,I created springboot app, which is connecting to postgres db, so I need a driver for that I have specified it in maven dependencies in 3 different ways:

1. ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
       <scope>runtime</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. ```
   <dependency> 
        <groupId>postgresql</groupId> 
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> 
       <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version> 
   </dependency>
   ```
3. ```
   <dependency> 
       <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> 
       <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> 
       <version>42.2.1</version> 
   </dependency>
   ```

and none of them worked, so I had to specify it by project properties in STS(eclipse) by going to project -> properties -> java build path -> libaries -> add external jar
and set path to downloaded before postgres jdcb jar file, although its already specified in maven dependencies as I left first postgres dependency declaration in pom.xml, so now driver is defined in Maven Dependencies and in Referenced Libraries and now it is working and I don't see an error :

> Cannot load driver class: org.postgresql.Driver

but whats intresting I downloaded the project on my other pc, where I didn't have to specify a driver manually, maven done the job itself. Somebody knows how that happend ?

Comment: this here works fine for me: `<dependency<groupId>org.postgresql</groupId><artifactId>postgresql</artifactId><version>9.4-1200-jdbc41</version></dependency>`

Comment: it's not the case i tried 30 versions, mentioned 3 main of them above and none of them works as maven dependency. I have to make reference to a jar file on my disk to make it work.

Comment: How are you launching your application? If from Eclipse, then maybe it doesn't perform an automatic import if the pom changes.

Comment: run application / run springboot app

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SpringBoot maven plugin? It should add all the required jars to the classpath. You should only need these 2 dependencies for postgres:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId> 
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId> 
        <version>42.2.1</version> 
    </dependency> 
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

You can find a sample pom here:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/relational-data-access/

Comment: yep, springboot dependency is in pom.xml and as I told there is one pc where I have to define it manually to make it work and there is another one where i don't have to because maven dependencies are working perfectly